# Erro de lógica ao remover itens repetidos de uma lista

Tags: python, lista

Estou fazendo um exercício onde devo criar uma função que remove itens repetidos de uma lista e retorna essa lista ordenada.

Meu código remove apenas alguns itens repetidos, mas deixa outros. Eu sei que existem outras soluções sem o uso do `del`, mas estou curioso sobre o que estou errando aqui, também aceito dicas que não envolvam a solução pro exercício.

Segue o código:

```
def remove_repetidos(lista):

    for itens in lista:
        if lista.count(itens) == 1:
            continue
        lista.remove(itens)

    return sorted(lista)
```

Caso eu coloque `[7,3,33,12,3,3,3,7,12,100]` como parâmetro ela devolve `[3, 3, 3, 7, 12, 33, 100]`.

Answer (score 5):

O problema é que o seu código modifica a lista dentro do `for in`. Você pode ver isso colocando um print dentro do loop.

```
>>> lista = [7,3,33,12,3,3,3,7,12,100]
>>> for itens in lista:
...     print(itens)
...     if lista.count(itens) == 1:
...         continue
...     lista.remove(itens)
... 
7
33
12
3
7
12
100
```

Em teoria deveríamos ver todos os itens no console, mas não é o que acontece.

Ao invés de usar a mesma lista, você pode criar uma nova:

```
>>> lista = [7,3,33,12,3,3,3,7,12,100]
>>> nova_lista = []
>>> for item in lista:
...     if not item in nova_lista:
...         nova_lista.append(item)
... 
>>> nova_lista
[7, 3, 33, 12, 100]
```

Ou simplesmente usar o `set` do Python:

```
>>> sorted(set([7,3,33,12,3,3,3,7,12,100]))
[3, 7, 12, 33, 100]
```